# AES128 decryption with NSData as key

Tags: objective-c, encryption, aes

I'm having a hard time decrypting `NSData` with `NSData key`. While decrypting with `NSString` everything works fine, yet with data as key, the method returns null `NSData`, eventhough status is ok, and key is also correct for that data. Here is my call

```
NSData *decrypted = [AES AES128DecryptWithKey:data key:mute];
NSLog(@"DECRYPTED >> %@", decrypted);
```

And my method

```
+ (NSData*)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSData*) data key:(NSData*)key {

    NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];
    NSLog(@"trying to decrypt >> %@ with key >> %@", data, key );

    size_t bufferSize           = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void* buffer                = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted    = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          [key bytes], kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [data bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);
    NSLog(@"cryptstatus %d", cryptStatus);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess)
    {
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

NSLog output:

```
trying to decrypt >> <152f052e 79436003 7a9c1a59 3b82f1c4>
with key >> <1b510e76 ac0000a1 027af26a e25ad24a>
cryptstatus 0
DECRYPTED >> <>
```

Looked into `RNEncryptor`, yet it only has aes256, while i need 128. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you're clear on the difference between *key* and *password*.  A key is a fixed-length set of bits that feeds directly into a cryptographic algorithm.  A password is a variable-length character string that is subsequently hashed and turned into a key.  If you encrypted your text supplying the key as a password then the encryption key was something different from what you thought it was.

Comment: (You should log "numBytesDecrypted".)

Comment: I know difference between key and password. Key is formed correctly. Tried nslog numBytesDecrypted and for some reason it is 0... What could it be?

Comment: I don't see any mention of `null` in the output. I've assumed zero bytes in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the single byte block only contains padding bytes. In that case zero bytes would be the expected outcome.

This is not the case for your ciphertext, in your case no padding was applied during encryption, so you will get a failure when you try and unpad the data.

Comment: Could you expand your question a little bit? I still don't get it totaly :)

Comment: I think replacing `kCCOptionPKCS7Padding` with `0` would give you no padding on CCCrypt, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: You were right.. It works with 0. But should I decrypt without padding? Thank you very much for your help, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Yep, there is the word "READY" in there. Must be plain text. Normally you should apply padding during encryption, yes. For decryption, keep to the mode used during encryption (obviously). Changed answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time helping me. Explained everything very clearly. Good luck!

Comment: Still don't understand why it would return `kCCSuccess`, equal to `0` though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23511/discussion-between-owlstead-and-datenshi)